# Profiler plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Does anyone know a 64 bit profiler JVisualVM exists or not for eclipse ? I have tried a lot to search for it on the net. Also please suggest if you know some really good profiler tools for eclipse ....

Thanks....

Comment: What do you mean by 64 bit profiler? A profiler that is compiled for 64 bit computers or that profiles 64 bit applications? Either case is weird since java is platform independent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using JProfiler for my current project and it's very helpful. Here is the site: http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

i think the **[TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/)** plugin is an excellent profiling plugin/tool available for Eclipse. However, be mindful of the fact that it shares the same JVM as Eclipse [as will be the case w/ any other Eclipse based plugin]. be careful to consider the overheads introduced due to this fact, into your calculations.

for example, don't profile something using TPTP, and another implementation using some external profiler [like VisualVM] and then compare the results. always compare results obtained from the same profiler tool.

Comment: TPTP is no longer supported as of Eclipse 3.7 Indigo. [TPTP Project Plan 2010](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I have the jdk 6 update 22 running on a windows 7 64 bit machine. When I downloaded the jdk I specified that my platform is Windowsx64. jvisualvm.exe comes included (you find it under Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin beside the other exe files). I just double clicked, took 5 minutes to figure out how it works and started profiling my application. Works like a charm...